# Facebook open graph & jstl

Tags: facebook, jstl, facebook-opengraph

HI i'm trying to modify open graph meta tag with jstl but facebook can't read this

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<c:out value="${question.text}"/>"/>
```

that'sthe beginning of my jsp page ... i really don't know what's wrong i tried everything but the title and the id doesn't appear in fb link

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>    


<jsp:useBean id="question" scope="request" class="com.qapro.entity.Question">         </jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="answer" scope="request" class="com.qapro.entity.Answer">      </jsp:useBean>

<c:set var="question.text" value="${question.text}" />
<c:set var="question.id" value="${question.id}" />


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>

<meta property="og:title" content="<c:out value="${question.text}"/>" />

<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fewcharts.com/DisplayQuestion?qId="<c:out value="${question.id}"/>" />                                                      
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://www.fewcharts.com/assets/img/bannerfb1200x630.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Fewcharts" />
<meta property="og:description" content= "Fewcharts is a ranking system focused mainly on music that allows you to find out who is the best. Through Fewcharts you can add your own preferences in 50 characters and create topic by voting with your friends. It's 100% free and will always be."/>
```

Comment: _“but facebook can't read this”_ – that is not Facebook’s fault, but yours. The source code of `www.fewcharts.com/DisplayQuestion?qId=1` shows the following meta tag, `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fewcharts.com/DisplayQuestion?qId="" />` – so _you_ did not output the parameter value correctly there. (And on top of that, you messed up the quotes.)

Comment: i know but in the body section of the same page ${question.id} works perfectly , so why    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fewcharts.com/DisplayQuestion?qId="<c:out value="${question.id}"/>" />  doesn't work???

Comment: Now if I request `…?qId=2`, it outputs `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fewcharts.com/DisplayQuestion?qId="2" />` – quotes are still wrong, the one before the `2` has to be deleted.

Comment: i tried to but it gives me error...

Comment: maybe is because there is not this?? <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="meta site name"/>

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug your markup > https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

What does the debugger tell you?